# which word should i use?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The ___ of the experiments are animals ( models / cases / agents / subjects ) . Please explain your answer

Comment: What did you learn in class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use subjects - meaning person (or animal) under the control of another (the one performing the experiment).  Agents implies taking an active role, which the animals are not doing when being experimented upon...presumably.